# Year end data rollover

Tags: mysql, database-design

I archive last years table and create a new table at the beginning of each year. I'd like to find a way to have one multi-year table so I don't have to manually change anything each year. Columns are: row (unique),date(primary),col1,col2,col3.. Users will type data (every column) into a form. I wanted to have a 'years' column that would be populated from year(date) with composite primary key(row,years). I also need primary key (row,year(date)). So each year we could start with row 1 and a new year. I even looked at and tried insert update triggers but I don't think that's the answer. What do you think? Is this too vague?

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? As far as i see it, all you need to do is to drop the uniqueness on the row column and then adding the keys you want. Note: you can only have ONE primary key on your table.

Comment: One thing that doesn't work is primary key (row,year(date)). I am using MySQL and asp classic. Another thing: the form has the option to enter from 1 to 50 rows at a time. I would like to be able to have a year column populate when the date is populated. Should I post one of my asp files here? Not sure how to do that.

Comment: I dont think you can have a function call year(date) in your key definition. If you have a year column then just use that. But maybe I misunderstand you.

Comment: Thanks. A year column would be great but I haven't figured how to auto generate it from date. I had the idea tonight to not create a new table each year but let the auto_incremented row just keep adding 1 for the next few years. I could use current year and last year in all queries and call it good. It would take about 10 years for the row number to reach 3650. That seems fine to me. Not very sophisticated but should work don't you think?

Comment: The only reason I need a row number is that users click on a row number to edit that row. This particular table has one row per day so maybe I don't even need a row. Maybe I could set it up so the the date is the button that is clicked on for editing and forget about row numbers. My other table can have multiple entries for each date. I'd use row numbers for that table.

Comment: the mysql year(date) will give you the year just fine. But you must use it in the insert and not in the key. Basically: insert into table_name (row, year) VALUES (someRowId,year(date)) and then the primary key is just (row,year).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in one of my Firebird databases (you didn't say which db you are using). First of all, you should have a primary key which is generated automatically - this will make life more simple. Secondly, you need one generator per year - or a table which has one field per year.

In this model, you have a table with two fields: year (primary key) and 'curvalue'. Every year you insert a new tuple such as (2012,0) or (2013, 0). You query this table to find the current value of the 'curvalue' field for the given year, then increment the curvalue field and use the incremented value in the tuple which you are inserting.

Using generators guarantees that you will always receive a unique number; using a table as I wrote above could cause problems if one row starts the process and then another row arrives.

Comment: MySQL. Cool. Didn't know about generators. What would I do at the end of each year? They don't get around to entering Dec stats until January.